# Problemas com colunas PHPExcel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, phpexcel

Comecei a realizar o desenvolvimento no meu sistema para eu gerasse um arquivo .xls de uma forma bem dinamica. Onde recebe os dados de uma pagina via POST, e são salvos em variaveis, segue o código:

```
<?php
$tabela = $_POST['txttabela'];
$p_colunas = $_POST['chkcolunas'];

$qtdColunas = count($p_colunas);
$condicao = "email IS NOT NULL";



// Incluimos a classe PHPExcel
include  '../../componentes/plugins/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Instanciamos a classe
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();



 // Podemos definir as propriedades do documento
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Floricultura Filippi")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Floricultura Filippi   ")
        ->setTitle("Floricultura Filippi - Pedidos")
        ->setSubject("Floricultura Filippi - Pedidos - Exportação")
        ->setDescription("Dados Exportados do Banco de Dados");

// Adicionamos um estilo de A1 até D1 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->applyFromArray(
        array('fill' => array(
                'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('rgb' => 'E0EEEE')
            ),
        )
);


if($p_colunas==""){
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Você tem que selecionar ao menos uma coluna");
    </script>
    <?php
}else{
    $sel_sintaxe = "SELECT "; # adiciona o INSERT  e a sua tabela, deixando o parateses aberto para concatenar no proximo $adc_sintaxe

    $row = 1;
    $col = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$qtdColunas; $i++){
         $p_colunas[$i];

         $sel_sintaxe.= $p_colunas[$i].", ";

        // Criamos as colunas
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $p_colunas[$i]);

        $col++;

    }

    $sel_sintaxe = substr($sel_sintaxe, 0, -2);  #Essa funcao ela devolve somente oq interessa, tirando  a ultima virgula e espaco do INSERT, que no caso daria erro
    $sel_sintaxe .= " FROM ".$tabela."";

    $RdNull = $_POST['rdNull'];
    $RdDescAsc = $_POST['rdDescAsc'];
    if(isset($_POST['txtlimite'])){
        $txtLimite = $_POST['txtlimite'];
    }

    if($RdNull || $RdDescAsc || isset($txtLimite)){

        if($RdNull=="nao"){
            $sel_sintaxe .=" WHERE ";
            for($i=0; $i<$qtdColunas; $i++){
                 $p_colunas[$i];

                  $sel_sintaxe.= $p_colunas[$i]." OR  ";

            }
            $sel_sintaxe = substr($sel_sintaxe, 0, -5);
            $sel_sintaxe.= " IS NOT NULL";
            $sel_sintaxe;
        }
        if($RdNull=="sim"){
            $sel_sintaxe .=" WHERE ";
            for($i=0; $i<$qtdColunas; $i++){
                 $p_colunas[$i];

                  $sel_sintaxe.= $p_colunas[$i]." OR  ";

            }
            $sel_sintaxe = substr($sel_sintaxe, 0, -5);
            $sel_sintaxe.= " IS NULL";

            $sel_sintaxe;
        }

        if($RdDescAsc){

            $sel_sintaxe.= " ORDER BY $tabela.id $RdDescAsc";
            $sel_sintaxe;
        }

        if(isset($txtLimite)){

            $sel_sintaxe.= " LIMIT $txtLimite";
            echo $sel_sintaxe;
        }
    }


    echo $sel_sintaxe;
    $sql_sel_tabela_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($sel_sintaxe);
    $sql_sel_tabela_preparado->execute();




// Alterando o tamanho da fonte
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:C1')->getFont()->setSize(14);

// Define a planilha ativa para o PHPExcel operar
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Define o título da planilha 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Planilha de Credeciamento 1');

// Define a largura das colunas de modo automático
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);

// Exemplo de preenchimento de dados de maneira dinâmica, a partir de um resultado do banco de dados por exemplo.
$linha = 3;
while($sql_sel_tabela_dados = $sql_sel_tabela_preparado->fetch()){
    $col = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$qtdColunas; $i++){
            $colunaInver = $p_colunas[$i];
            //$colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($XX);
            echo $colString = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col);

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue($colString. $linha, $sql_sel_tabela_dados[$colunaInver]);

                echo $linha++;
                $col++;

        }

}

// Salva  o arquivo 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("ff_pedidos.com.br.xls");
//$objWriter->save('php://output');
}
?>
```

Ao gerar o Excel, a cada tres dados, deveria quebrar linha e ficar uma coisa embaixo da outra veja como esta ficando:
[image: Exemplo do .xls]

Queria que ficasse uma coisa embaixo da outra, bem organizado alguém pode me dizer meu erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, o problema é que você não está re-setando o valor `$col` a cada nova linha, então ela continua aumentando indefinidamente.

Setar `$col = 0` a cada nova linha de dados deve resolver:

```
while($sql_sel_tabela_dados = $sql_sel_tabela_preparado->fetch()){
    $col = 0; // migrado para dentro do while   
    for($i=0; $i<$qtdColunas; $i++){
```

Comment: É exatamente isso vou verificar

Comment: Quase deu certo, olha como ficou editei o código com suas modificações e a imagem também, porém os dados não estão um do lado do outro :( . Como que eu poderia por uma coisa no lado da outra. Obrigado até agora!

Comment: Consegui resolver jogando o $linha++ fora do for e colocando dentro do while

Comment: massa, era o que eu ia sugerir!

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, Agradeço sua ajuda, é tanto detalhe novo que passei em branco nos mínimos detalhes!